# What can be said about a space with solvable fundamental group?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Let $X$ be a topological space. Suppose $\pi_1(X)$ is solvable, can we say something about $X$ ?

This question is probably broad, however I am interested in knowing if there is anything at all that can be said about such a space (or perhaps its universal cover, if it exists)

Thank you.

Comment: Since solvable groups are nilpotent, and a nice chunk of algebraic topology requires you restrict to nilpotent fundamental group, it says you can do a nice chunk of algebraic topology. I don't know what else to say.

Comment: Solvable groups are nilpotent? Isn't it the other way around? See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144410/nilpotent-groups-are-solvable)

Comment: @MikeMiller, Could you give me an example of or a reference to a book/article(s) that deal with this nice chunk of algebraic topology. Thank you.

Comment: Oops, I guess I was falling asleep when I wrote that. Sorry! (I'm thinking, off the top of my head, of rational homotopy theory, but I remember this assumption appearing elsewhere.)